Keeping display contiguration (with panning) after disconnecting external monitor from laptop
Setup
Laptop: Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6 (with Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050) eDP-2
External monitor: Asus ZenScreen MB16AH Monitor 15.6" FHD (connected via USB C) DP-1-2

Other Info
The external monitor only works when the GeForce is active as the USB C display mode is hardwired to the external GPU
Nvidia driver version: 550.54.14
KDE Frameworks: Version 5.103.0
Distro: OpenSUSE 15.5
xrandr -q
output
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
DP-1-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm

As I often need to be on the road, when I disconnect the external monitor, KDE (gracefully) places all windows on the laptop’s monitor .
What I want is when Ι disconnect the external monitor to keep the same display configuration panning for the external monitor.
I haven’t tried anything so far as I don’t know where to begin.
I’m guessing a virtual output would be used?
